# Draw on Panel after ButtonPress

Tags: java, swing

I am a bit stuck on this Problem, I am not programming a lot but I wanted to draw something on a panel in java swing (after pressing a button)

I don't know how to do it, but I found out, that I can draw on a panel on the creation of the panel ( see code) 
now I want something to not draw the line on creation but after I pressed a button ( so a code that I could put into my ButtonActionPerformed Method would be nice.
Hope someone can help
Robert

```
jPanel16 = new javax.swing.JPanel() {
public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

    Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(10, 100, 40, 400);
    g2.setColor(Color.blue);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
    g2.draw(line);
}};
```

Comment: You need to model your data, this way, when you press a button, you can change the model and share it with your drawing panel which can use it to draw what ever you want

Comment: For example create an ArrayList of items you want to draw. Then in the paintComponent() method you just iterate through the ArrayList to paint all the Items. For an basic example of this approach check out the `DrawOnComponent` example found in [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/)

Answer (score 1):

I hope below example would show you how to achieve this.

Here, the responsibility of `Drawing` class is to draw a line. This line is provided by outside. So, if the line exists `Drawing` class draws it. Otherwise it skips drawing because there is nothing to draw.

In this example, line is given to `Drawing` object when user clicks the button.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

public class DrawOnEvent {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Drawing drawing = new Drawing();

    JButton button = new JButton("Draw");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        drawing.setLine(new Line2D.Double(10, 100, 80, 200));
        drawing.repaint();
      }
    });

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(drawing, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setBounds(300, 200, 400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class Drawing extends JPanel {

  private Line2D line;

  void setLine(Line2D line) {
    this.line = line;
  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if (line != null) {
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setColor(Color.blue);
      g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
      g2.draw(line);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be nicer to use `frame.pack()` instead of `frame.setBounds(300, 200, 400, 300);` (and give `Draw` preferred size)